# Array Segmentation Fault C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

First off, I am not very experienced with C.

I am having to deal with arrays for a problem I need to solve, I have managed to simplify the issue to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char array[5] = {"hello"}

int main() {

printf(%s\n", array[0]);

return (0);
}
```

In this case I am just trying to print the 'h', yet I get a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: use `%c` instead of `%s`.

Comment: omit the {} when declaring the char and don't forget the ;

Comment: Also, note that your string isn't NUL-terminated and that you are missing a `"` in the `printf`.

Comment: Please copy-paste your program instead of typing out yourself.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the typos, I'm currently working on two computers and the code was not too long so I re-typed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of errors to be fixed,

```
printf(%s\n", array[0]);
```

Here, you are trying to print a `char`, try

```
printf("%c\n", array[0]);
```

---

You are missing a `;`

```
char array[5] = {"hello"}
                         ^
```

---

While declaring a string literal, you don't need the `{}`

```
char array[] = "hello";
```

Comment: As for the slightly more complicated problem. I am trying to print an asterisk letter line by line, in order to be able to eventually print other letters side by side.  *Ah can't i post code in the comments?

Comment: @MiguelRestrepo I din't get you, can you give an example. And, if its not related to this one then ask a different question separately.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website. I have now edited the OP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MiguelRestrepo Don't edit the question like that, it will make the answers invalid. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all lets see what %s does - it expects it corresponding to be an address. It starts reading from that address byte by byte as if all these bytes were characters and keeps printing them until it finds the null `\0` character.

Now, 
`char array[5] = {"hello"}`
means `array[0]` is 'h' - that's correct. But what's wrong is that you are using %s to print it. So, %s considers 'h' to be an address (well to be precise the ascii value of 'h' as the address). Which is 104 i guess. This can be an address alright but cant be accessed by your normal program (too much details here) and hence the segmentation fault

So, in short use %c to print characters.

Also one thing: `array[5]` is not enough to hold "hello" - as it is actually 6 characters the sixth is the terminating '\0' character which is automatically appended to c strings.

Comment: Thank you for the more in-depth explanation.